# Putting system date into a text field in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm new to swift and would appreciate some help with string manipulation. I'm trying to get the current date off NSDate and put it into a text field for an app I'm working on. I tried to use NSDateFormatter to put the ios system date into the international form or dd-MM-yyyy, but I just keep getting all these errors and nothing works. I could use the American date format, I just really need it to work. I don't really know swift that much, but I know that other tutorials I tried to follow on stack overflow directed me to put some code in the view controller using NSDate. I worked on some other tutorials and tried to make them do what I needed to and this is the result. It used to create a date and timestamp but I tried to cut the parts out that deal with time. I think I just made it worse.

```
func convertDateFormatter(date: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

 guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else {
     assert(false, "no date from string")
     return ""
 }

 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
 let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
 return timeStamp

 }
```

My version of swift doesn't recognize NSDate, it wants to change it to just Date, I don't know how it affects how I am supposed to go about doing this. I changed it to just Date in the code and it still doesn't work.

In addition, yesterday my mobile apps teacher and I tried to equate a custom variable and the text field, but it does not work.

```
 var UIDateStamp = UITextField().self
```

I could be wording my search incorrectly but I have searched this same query all the different ways I could come up with, but every solution I have tried thus far gives me a lot of errors that my coding class and I cannot solve.

I would greatly appreciate help with this issue.

Comment: in which format you have passed date to this function convertDateFormatter(date: String) ?

Comment: Use Date class instead of NSDate class in Swift

Comment: This is very basic stuff. It seems your *teacher* needs a teacher, too. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to system date they you need create function without parameter.

**Swift 3**

```
 func convertDateFormatter() -> String {
      let date = Date()
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // change format as per needs
      let result = formatter.string(from: date)
      return result 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works well, except I still cannot put the result into a text field. I tried to set result as a variable but I cannot declare the variable twice or equate the string to the text field I want it to go in.
This doesn't work:             

        
        ~~ let formatter.string(from: date) = (RoundStyleTextField.text)~~         

this does not work either:

        ~~var result =  let formatter.string(from: date) [New line]   

        var result = (RoundStyleTextField.text)~~          


Do you know how to put it into a text field?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a date format depending on the current locale use the `timeStyle` and `dateStyle` properties.

This code – as computed property – returns `M/d/yy` for the US locale

```
var timeStamp : String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    return formatter.string(from: Date())
}
```

A date style `medium` returns `MMM d, yyyy`